# Why does the value of a dictionary variable persist between method calls?

Tags: python, language-design, mutable

This is not a homework question. I came across this when I was attempting to answer a question on SO. It intrigued me. I searched online for a while and could not find anything. Here is the code:

```
def unravel(data, resultsdict={}):
    for k in data:
        if isinstance(data[k],dict):
            unravel(data[k], resultsdict)
        else:
            resultsdict[k] = data[k]
    return resultsdict
```

Run:

```
>>> print unravel({'a': 'b'})
{'a': 'b'}
>>> print unravel({'c': 'd'})
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Why does the dictionary returned by the first method get used in the second call, in spite of the default argument `resultsdict={}`?